# How do I initialize an AFNEtworking class in Swift prior to viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm new to Swift. Trying to understand how to initialize my AFNetworking class prior to view did load. I'm accessing the class from the ViewController like this

```
var serverAnalytics = ServerAnalytics()
print(serverAnalytics.today)
```

Problem is the stored variables in the class from the JSON file do not initialize prior to viewDidload. Therefore the properties are default/blank.
Using AFNetworking and SwiftyJSON.

```
import Foundation

class ServerAnalytics {

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    var today:Double! = 0
    var complete:Bool! = false


    init(){
    manager.GET("http://www.somerandomjsonurl",
        parameters: nil,
        progress: nil,
        success: { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask,responseObject: AnyObject?) in
            if let responseObject = responseObject {
                //print("Response: " + responseObject.description)
                let json = JSON(responseObject)
                 self.today = json["salesdata"]["list"][0]["todays_sales"].double!

            }

        },
        failure: { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask?,error: NSError) in
            print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is that your `ServerAnalytics` class is populating those values using a network call, meaning that you can't really tell *when* they're going to be populated - or if they will at all if the network request fails for some reason.

So instead of thinking about how to make sure those values are populated before `viewDidLoad` runs, think about how to make your view controller do the right thing whether the values are populated or not, and how to have your `ServerAnalytics` class tell the view controller when the values are ready. Using the delegate pattern, much like UIKit does, seems a good strategy for this.

Comment: Agree this is the right way to think about it.  Some other solutions besides a delegate pattern would be sending an NSNotification, a subject-observer design pattern, reactive cocoa signal (but ONLY IF you're already using Reactive Cocoa; it's waaaaaay too heavyweight to include just for a solution to this sort of problem), YMMV.  I would unequivocally **not** recommend direct KVO; there are too many issues to make it a viable solution for anything more than the most basic of apps.